# ActiveRecord Model without id: to_json does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database

I have a model (based on a database view) with no id. (There is key constisting of three attributes that I could use  as a primary key, but rails won't let me do that).

When I run `.to_json` on the model I get an error:

```
 TypeError:
   nil is not a symbol nor a string
 # /Users/bjelline/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activemodel-4.0.13/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:109:in `block in serializable_hash'
```

Looking into `serialization.rb` I found a variable `attribute_names` that not only
contains the attributes from my table, but also an extra value `nil`:

```
attribute_names=["event_id", "course_id", "title", ..., "site_name", "allDay", nil]
```

And this nil causes the error.  I suspect that it is caused by the table
not having a primary key.

Is there a way to fix `.to_json` without having to add a primary key?

Comment: bjelli have you try this: `object.to_json(except: :id)`?

Comment: yes. except turns all its' arguments into strings before removing them from the attribute list.  So it can't b used to remove `nil`, only `""` (the empty string)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the underlying cause (primary key or seomthing else), the `nil` in the attribute_names is the problem.  attribute_names comes from `attributes`, which can be overridden.

attributes returns a hash with the keys being the names of the attributes. It containts `nil => nil` in my case.  To remove the key `nil` I can use `except` like so:

```
def attributes
  super.except(nil)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who are reading this because of the `nil is not a symbol nor a string` error and who DO have an ID field: make sure that id field is the Primary Key of the table.